# RAD PDF Service Message Worker Thread Unknown Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, iis, permissions

I try to open My PDF through [RadPdf](http://www.radpdf.com/) control  but i get rendering error . i check the event viewer and get the following data :
to fix the problem i have to create `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\RadPdfTemp\` and the admin every period of time empty the temp and this folder removed , i try to create this folder in my my web site with the required permissions but still get the same error !!!

---

```
 this.rad_pdf.CreateDocument("Document Name", pdfData);
```

I get `pdfData` through :

```
 private byte[] AddReportToResponse(LocalReport followsReport)
    {
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;
        string[] streams = new string[100];
        Warning[] warnings = new Warning[100];
        byte[] pdfStream = followsReport.Render("PDF", "", out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);


        return pdfStream;
    }
```

---

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   RAD PDF
Event Category: None
Event ID:   0
Date:       4/21/2013
Time:       2:33:50 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   -----
Description:
Event Category
-----------------
PdfService

Event Description
-----------------
RAD PDF Service Message Worker Thread Unknown Exception
Exception Type:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
Exception Message:
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\RadPdfTemp\p476.tmp'.
Exception Stack Trace:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes)
   at #Ew.#Rw.#ix()
   at #Ew.#Rw.#9w()

Event User
-----------------
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Event Version
-----------------
2.12.0.0

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: Clarifying "the admin every period of time empty the temp and this folder removed" may help others help you.  What do you mean by this?  Do you mean that you create `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\RadPdfTemp` manually, which fixes the issue for a while, but an admin (job) empties `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP` at intervals, removing the `RadPdfTemp` subfolder?

Comment: Also worth clarifying to help others help you: "i try to create this folder in my my web site with the required permissions but still get the same error !!!"  So when you try to create `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\RadPdfTemp` in your web code, it _is_ created successfully?  What are the required permissions - the permissions you set when you create the folder manually I assume?  Have you tried writing out the path of the folder you are creating in your web code, then pasting it into the Windows Run... dialog or Windows Explorer to confirm that it opens (what you expect)?

Comment: @J0e3gan :: `Do you mean that you create C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\RadPdfTemp manually, which fixes the issue for a while, but an admin (job) empties C:\WINDOWS\TEMP at intervals, removing the RadPdfTemp subfolder?`

yeah this is exactly what i did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the temp folder exist otherwise create it before you open the PDF file. That will make sure the folder is there and no exception is thrown.

```
string tempDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "RadPdfTemp");

if (!Directory.Exists(tempDirectory))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectory);

this.rad_pdf.CreateDocument("Document Name", pdfData);
```